# @Media Query - How do I Break a Horizontal Scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a horizontal scroll that I would like to turn into a vertical scroll when the viewing device is 480px or less.

Currently my corresponding HTML is:

```
<!-- section that contains all pics -->
<section id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <article class="post">
    <p><img src="img/scroll/01_scroll.jpg" alt="test image 1" title="test image" width="994" height="620" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-240" /></p>
    </article>
</section>
<!-- close section -->
```

There is an HTML document-side script that goes as follows:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#wrapper").wrapInner("<table><tr>");
        $(".post").wrap("<td>");
    });     
    $(function() {
        $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 50);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

And the corresponding CSS is:

```
#wrapper {
   float:left;
   margin:110px 0 0 0;
   padding:0 0 0 250px;
   background:#fff;
   position:relative;
   z-index:2;
   border-bottom:solid 20px #fff;
}

#wrapper img {
   color:#fff;
   width:auto;
}

#wrapper iframe {
   color:#fff;
}

.post {
   padding:0 10px 0 0;
   background:#fff;
   height:100%;
}
```

My media query is:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
   {
```

and I would like for when this happens (480px or less), the script stops scrolling horizontally, begins to scroll vertically and resizes for maximum width and proper height.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like using jquery to wrap those elements in table cells is excessive.  My inclination would be to get rid of that and just use a responsive float on the Article elements.
So new js:

```
<script>

    $(function() {
        $("body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 50);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    </script>
```

And new CSS:

```
.post {
   padding:0 10px 0 0;
   background:#fff;
   height:100%;
   display:block;
   float:left;
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
   .post {
       float:none;
     }
   }
```

Somewhere after your articles you'll need to add a clear:both; rule...

Comment: Going to try this right now, I don't understand what a "clear:both" rule is or does.

Comment: Didn't work.  When I removed the table wrapping script, it broke.  It did scroll vertically then...  but all other aspects were off.  Which leads to a second question, is it possible to REMOVE IDs and Classes via @media query?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!!

The answer, as always, was right in front of me.  The issue is that I'm fighting over .post and #wrapper when the script created a table!  With this in mind I manipulated the table and viola!   vertical scroll only on mobile!  See below:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
#wrapper {
   top:155px;
   width:auto;
   margin:0 0 0 10px;
   padding:0 0 0 0;
   background:#fff;
   position:absolute;
   z-index:2;
}

table {
   margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

td {
   display:block;
   padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

tr {
   max-width:100%;
   height:auto;
}

table img {
   max-width:100%;
   height:auto;
}
```

what a relief... now to find out what happened to my footer...